# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to arrange n distinct objects in 5 distinct boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am having trouble with this question, please take a look at it:

Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to arrange n distinct objects in 5 distinct boxes.

this is my discrete math assignment and there is no example for this problem in my book .. and i cant find it on internet too.. Please help me..  thank you :)

Comment: Do you know about stirling partition numbers?

Comment: its a first time i heard it..

Comment: Scratch that. I thought each box has to be filled. But since that is not required, see Brian M. Scott's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct objects in $5$ distinct boxes. Clearly $a_1=5$. (You can even start at $a_0=1$. There’s just one way to arrange $0$ objects: you put none of them in each box.) Now suppose that you know $a_n$ for some $n$; what must $a_{n+1}$ be? Say that the objects are labelled $1$ through $n+1$. You put the first $n$ objects into the boxes; you can do this in $a_n$ ways. Then you put the $(n+1)$-st object into one of the $5$ boxes; in how many different ways can you do this? And how do you combine that number with $a_n$ to get $a_{n+1}$, the number of ways to put all $n+1$ objects into the boxes? That formula is the desired recurrence relation.

Note that in this problem it’s easy to write down a closed form for $a_n$. If the boxes are numbered $1$ through $5$, each distribution of $n$ objects numbered $1$ through $n$ to the boxes can be thought of as a function from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. How many of those are there? You can use that knowledge to check that your recurrence actually makes sense.

Comment: I presume you mean $a_n$ when you are writing $s_n$.

Comment: @Shahab: Yep; thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: I got from combination, can we use that? ,, a0 become 1, a1 become 5, a2 become 10, a3 became 10 and a4 become 5..and a5 become 1 again? is that right? then how about the recurrence ?

Comment: @FaqihahNurZahirahM: Your $a_2$ is already far too small. There are $a_1=5$ ways choose a box for the first object. Then there are also $5$ ways to choose a box for the second object, so there are altogether $5\cdot5=25$ different possible outcomes. This has nothing to do with binomial coefficients.

Comment: And then.. a3 is became 5.5.5 = 125 ways?

Comment: @FaqihahNurZahirahM: Yes, by the same reasoning.

Comment: Then would it be my recurrence become an = 5an-1?

Comment: @FaqihahNurZahirahM: Yes, $a_n=5a_{n-1}$ is indeed the recurrence relation.

Comment: I got it now.. Thanks for your help

Comment: @FaqihahNurZahirahM: You’re welcome!